# Managing DbContext lifetime in ASP.NET Core SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I have implemented an ASP.Core SignalR Application.

A shared hub class is invoking a signal to all its client on every 10 seconds
from class `SharedHub` (this class is not inherited from `Hub` it has logic to get `IHubContext` to invoke)

```
public void Tick(){
    var time = _context.table.time;
    invoke('tick', time.tick);
}
```

Also in the same class once a new connection established a method called to update database

```
public void UpdateSocketConnection(int connectionId){
    var connection =_context.connection;
    connection.id = connectionId;
    _context.saveChanges();
}
```

Problem with this implementation is if the connection is currently calling `Tick()` method and also a client connected the same time. `_context` throws an error saying:

> _context in use.

(I'll update exact error message once I reproduce).

What I have done ?

I have implemented a factory method to get a new instance of `_context` on top of every method

```
public void Tick(){
    var time = factory.GetContext().time;
    invoke('tick', time.tick);
}

public void UpdateSocketConnection(int connectionId){
    var context = Factory.getContext();

    var connection =context.connection;
    connection.id = connectionId;
    context .saveChanges();
}
```

This actually solved the problem. But it seems not the right thing to do. I am not sure of the performance when getting a new context every time on top of every method. this seems bad practice.

I want to know what are the possible implementation for this scenario.

Comment: could you show the hub declaration, and the initialization of `_context`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first approach `DbContext` is shared between operations at the same time and it cause error and unexpected result. To avoid create and dispose `DbContext` every time in the second approach, `DbContextPooling` can help performance.

A pool of reusable instances can be created. Instead of disposing an instance, it returns to the pool and resets the instance to its default state. So instead of creating a new instance every time, the code will first check if there is an instance available in the pool or not.

You can enable `DbContextPooling` in `Configure` method in `startup` class:

```
services.AddDbContextPool<YourContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

The default pool size value is 128. Read [this article](https://neelbhatt.com/2018/02/27/use-dbcontextpooling-to-improve-the-performance-net-core-2-1-feature/) for more info.